# How do I fix this code to pass data between activities in Android Application?

Tags: java, android

I've set up a calculator in one activity (OHNSCalculatorSkillsCourses) which does a simple calculation and gives result.

I want the result displayed in another activity (OHNSCalculator).

I've updated with the two Activity codes below.

**OHNSCalculatorSkillsCourses:**

```
public class OHNSCalculatorSkillsCourses extends Activity{

EditText editText3SC;
TextView textViewResultSC;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ohns_calculator_skillscourses);

    editText3SC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3SC);
    textViewResultSC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResultSC);

    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    editText3SC.setText(prefs.getString("autoSave4", ""));

    String result= prefs.getString("autoSave4","");
    if(!result.equals("") && !result.isEmpty()){
        textViewResultSC.setText(addNumbers());
        prefs.getString("autoSave4","");
    }
    editText3SC.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResultSC.setText(addNumbers());
        }


        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            prefs.edit().putString("autoSave4", s.toString()).commit();
        }


    });

}

public void showGreetings(View view)
{
    String button_text;
    button_text = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
    if (button_text.equals("Back"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,OHNSCalculator.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        Intent getScore = new Intent(OHNSCalculatorSkillsCourses.this, OHNSCalculator.class);
        getScore.putExtra("SkillsScore", textViewResultSC.getText().toString());
        startActivity(getScore);

    }}

private String addNumbers() {
    float number1;
    if (!editText3SC.getText().toString().isEmpty() && editText3SC.getText().length() > 0) {
        number1 = Float.parseFloat(editText3SC.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number1 = 0;
    }
    float sum = (float) (number1 * 0.5);
    if (sum > 1) sum = 1;
    return sum + "";
}}
```

**OHNSCalculator:**

```
public class OHNSCalculator extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ohns_calculator);
    Intent mgetScore = getIntent();
    float textViewResultSC = Float.parseFloat(mgetScore.getStringExtra("SkillScore"));

}

public void showGreetings(View view)
{
    String button_text;
    button_text = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
    if (button_text.equals("Surgical Experience (Max 6)"))
    {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,OHNSCalculatorSurgicalExperience.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (button_text.equals("Skills Courses (Max 1)"))
    {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,OHNSCalculatorSkillsCourses.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (button_text.equals("Qualifications (Max 5)"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,OHNSCalculatorQualifications.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (button_text.equals("Presentations (Max 3)"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,OHNSCalculatorPresentations.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (button_text.equals("Publications (Max 5)"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,OHNSCalculatorPublications.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}}
```

I am still getting this error

**Logcat**

[image]

Comment: `editText3SC.getText().toString() != ""` should be `!editText3SC.getText().toString().isEmpty()`

Comment: Ideally there shouldnt be any code after your startActivity and your statActivity should be called on some action. So can you tell me that at the start you have called startActivity inside which method?

Comment: Looks like you have done it in onStart or onCreate of your SkillsCourses Activity. Is it true?

Comment: Yep in onCreate

Comment: @J.Thomas can you update your both classes here

Answer (score 7):

First use compare strings with `equals` not `!=`

Second : don't send the `TextView` reference instead send the value

```
getScore.putExtra("SkillsScore",textViewResultSC.getText().toString());
```

Third : execute lines of putting value in `intent` object and startActvity after you have data

Fourth : use parsing to convert string into float wherever it is required

Comment: Sir @Pavneet_Singh I want to ask a question about my stackoverflow reputation where I can ask,

Comment: @UltimateDevil [meta stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) is the place and please  pavneet only , i am not that old :)

Comment: @J. Thomas you have a typo mistake which is causing the error , so use `mgetScore.getStringExtra("SkillsScore")` instead of `mgetScore.getStringExtra("SkillScore")`

Comment: Ok, thank you and You have reputations Which entitles you to be called SIr, and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass **`Intent`** after getting values not to **`onCreate()`** of your **`Activity`**

you have to **Change** your

```
Intent getScore = new Intent(SkillsCourses.this, Calculatorresult.class);
getScore.putExtra("SkillsScore",  textViewResultSC.getText().toString());
startActivity(getScore);
```

and you can get the result by using below code in your 
 **`OnCreate()`** of **`Calculatorresult.class`**

```
Intent mgetScore = getIntent();
String textViewResultSC = mgetScore.getStringExtra("SkillsScore");
```

**OR**

**Note :** if you want to your **`textViewResultSC`** result in `float` then you can use below code :

```
Intent mgetScore = getIntent();
float textViewResultSC = Float.parseFloat(mgetScore.getStringExtra("SkillsScore"));
```

**EDIT**

your class must be

```
public class Calculatorresult extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculatorresult);
    Intent mgetScore = getIntent();
    float textViewResultSC = Float.parseFloat(mgetScore.getStringExtra("SkillsScore"));

}
```

**EDIT 2**

You are passing wrong **`key`** in `float textViewResultSC = Float.parseFloat(mgetScore.getStringExtra("SkillScore"));`

Because you have passed the **`value`** from intent with **`key` : `SkillsScore`** and you are getting **`value`** using **`key` : `SkillScore`** this cause **`NullPointerException`**

You need to change this

```
float textViewResultSC = Float.parseFloat(mgetScore.getStringExtra("SkillScore"));
```

to

```
float textViewResultSC = Float.parseFloat(mgetScore.getStringExtra("SkillsScore"));
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error on Calculatorresult.class saying the method getStringExtra in class Intent cannot be applied to given types

Comment: Yep Pavneet I've taken your suggestions on board 
@UltimateDevil Still getting error: 
Error:(23, 60) error: method getStringExtra in class Intent cannot be applied to given types;
required: String
found: String,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: it will be String textViewResultSC = mgetScore.getStringExtra("SkillScore");

Comment: Sorry, Sir @Pavneet_Singh actually i was making silly mistake

Comment: @J.Thomas this need to be work see the updated answer

Comment: Errors gone but just crashing now!

Comment: @J.Thomas look at your logcat view and post the error details and give a shot first solving it by yourself , it will not be hard with the details

Comment: Check your crash logs  and try to solve if you can't then update to your question @J.Thomas

Comment: @UltimateDevil where would you put the intent object and startActivity lines in the SkillsCourses activity? I know the startActivity should be at the end and after the calculations but anything after my return function is unreachable- any idea how to get around this? That's my main issue

Comment: @J.Thomas you need to create a button for going to another activity and put that intent or startActivity onClick event of that button

Comment: @J.Thomas have you got it

Comment: @UltimateDevil still can't get it... Crashing whenever I add in this code: 
Intent mgetScore = getIntent();
float textViewResultSC = Float.parseFloat(mgetScore.getStringExtra("SkillScore"));

I've added the logcat above

Comment: @J.Thomas i have updated your question but you need to update your both classes complete code here

Comment: @UltimateDevil thanks!! I've updated with the new classes as they are now

Comment: just remove Intent intent = new Intent(this,OHNSCalculator.class);
        startActivity(intent); from your show greeting method of OHNSCalculatorSkillsCourses  and try again  @J.Thomas

Comment: Still crashing with same logcat- the line of code causing the crash is:         float textViewResultSC = Float.parseFloat(mgetScore.getStringExtra("SkillScore")); from OHNSCalculator but I can't work out why

Comment: @UltimateDevil oops can't believe I missed that thanks- but still getting nullpointerexception and crash despite fixing

Comment: Yep exactly the same java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference

Comment: Can you upload your project to github and provide me that link because I am not getting what are you doing wrong now in your code you are not using trim but still errors. Maybe I can help better